# How to run Grails 3.1.x Application with JAVA

Tags: java, grails

Within my test environment I want to start the grails application with java, there is no need for a separate tomcat instance. I create the WAR file by calling

```
gradle assemble
```

After that I deploying the application using JAVA:

```
java -Dgrails.env=dev -jar build/libs/mcc-0.1.war
```

The startup works, but after firing the first request I'm getting a enormes exception:

> 2016-06-16 17:24:07,388 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [index.gsp:14] Error executing tag : Unable to create URL for mapping [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?] and parameters [{action=upload}]. Parameter [controller] is required, but was not specified!] with root cause
>   grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException: Unable to create URL for mapping [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?] and parameters [{action=upload}]. Parameter [controller] is required, but was not specified!
>       at grails.artefact.gsp.TagLibraryInvoker$Trait$Helper.methodMissing(TagLibraryInvoker.groovy:88)
>       at Users_david_workspace_mcc_index_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(Users_david_workspace_mcc_index_gsp:26)
>       at Users_david_workspace_mcc_index_gsp.run(Users_david_workspace_mcc_index_gsp:29)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2016-06-16 17:24:07,452 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet grailsDispatcherServlet threw exception
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1229)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:445)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:304)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:179)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2016-06-16 17:24:07,455 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/error]
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1229)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:445)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:304)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:179)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/605, the temporary solution was to run the java command directly within the folder, where the WAR file is located. In my case:

```
java -Dgrails.env=dev -jar mcc-0.1.war
```